# how to dynamically/internally align some specific HTML data to right using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

i am populating a HTML table with JSON data, i have json as it is as i want my table i am just writing java script code to dynamically populate the table, so here i am facing issues to make some changes in my html table internally

some points which i have to change in HTML table are

1. I want to align all the data which are in no form to right except headers TOTAL  1 ,outlet because they are string so its ok for them to me left align

i am using **tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
              tabCell.classList.add("text-right");** in my code but its aligning all data to right

here is my code

```
 tableValue=[
  {
    "5": "4341",
    "6": "12235",
    "7": "37135",
    "8": "53522",
    "9": "43688",
    "10": "39965",
    "11": "32024",
    "12": "49631",
    "13": "84770",
    "14": "107020",
    "15": "60046",
    "16": "50656",
    "17": "63183",
    "18": "63381",
    "19": "59317",
    "20": "49595",
    "21": "28752",
    "22": "1518",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "TOTAL 1",
    "TOTAL": "840779"
  },
  {
    "5": "605",
    "6": "6073",
    "7": "8324",
    "8": "15596",
    "9": "13424",
    "10": "15865",
    "11": "12101",
    "12": "16792",
    "13": "31889",
    "14": "39439",
    "15": "19949",
    "16": "17571",
    "17": "21105",
    "18": "20803",
    "19": "22551",
    "20": "19865",
    "21": "9632",
    "22": "5",
    "OUTLET": "JAYANAGAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "291589"
  },
  {
    "5": "3736",
    "6": "5177",
    "7": "10598",
    "8": "12227",
    "9": "12020",
    "10": "12329",
    "11": "11412",
    "12": "20662",
    "13": "32000",
    "14": "37438",
    "15": "21690",
    "16": "18499",
    "17": "23042",
    "18": "22779",
    "19": "19878",
    "20": "16754",
    "21": "14371",
    "22": "1513",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "296125"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1281",
    "8": "1451",
    "9": "2285",
    "10": "2013",
    "11": "2917",
    "12": "2965",
    "13": "6437",
    "14": "9538",
    "15": "4269",
    "16": "3579",
    "17": "6257",
    "18": "7031",
    "19": "5187",
    "20": "2667",
    "21": "460",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "58337"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1514",
    "8": "577",
    "9": "3150",
    "10": "3106",
    "11": "2758",
    "12": "2891",
    "13": "5344",
    "14": "6653",
    "15": "3921",
    "16": "5171",
    "17": "5953",
    "18": "6143",
    "19": "5959",
    "20": "3255",
    "21": "150",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "56545"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "341",
    "7": "8838",
    "8": "12335",
    "9": "7872",
    "10": "4370",
    "11": "1829",
    "12": "3348",
    "13": "3502",
    "14": "5581",
    "15": "4231",
    "16": "2524",
    "17": "2236",
    "18": "2008",
    "19": "1796",
    "20": "4870",
    "21": "289",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "KOLAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "65970"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "644",
    "7": "6580",
    "8": "11336",
    "9": "4937",
    "10": "2282",
    "11": "1007",
    "12": "2973",
    "13": "5598",
    "14": "8371",
    "15": "5986",
    "16": "3312",
    "17": "4590",
    "18": "4617",
    "19": "3946",
    "20": "2184",
    "21": "3850",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "72213"
  }
]

function addTable(tableValue) {
        var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first

        var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
                                                            // are number
        var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
        col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


          for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];

            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
              tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
        table.classList.add("table");
         table.classList.add("table-striped");
         table.classList.add("table-bordered");


        }
addTable(tableValue)
```

```js
tableValue=[
  {
    "5": "4341",
    "6": "12235",
    "7": "37135",
    "8": "53522",
    "9": "43688",
    "10": "39965",
    "11": "32024",
    "12": "49631",
    "13": "84770",
    "14": "107020",
    "15": "60046",
    "16": "50656",
    "17": "63183",
    "18": "63381",
    "19": "59317",
    "20": "49595",
    "21": "28752",
    "22": "1518",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "TOTAL 1",
    "TOTAL": "840779"
  },
  {
    "5": "605",
    "6": "6073",
    "7": "8324",
    "8": "15596",
    "9": "13424",
    "10": "15865",
    "11": "12101",
    "12": "16792",
    "13": "31889",
    "14": "39439",
    "15": "19949",
    "16": "17571",
    "17": "21105",
    "18": "20803",
    "19": "22551",
    "20": "19865",
    "21": "9632",
    "22": "5",
    "OUTLET": "JAYANAGAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "291589"
  },
  {
    "5": "3736",
    "6": "5177",
    "7": "10598",
    "8": "12227",
    "9": "12020",
    "10": "12329",
    "11": "11412",
    "12": "20662",
    "13": "32000",
    "14": "37438",
    "15": "21690",
    "16": "18499",
    "17": "23042",
    "18": "22779",
    "19": "19878",
    "20": "16754",
    "21": "14371",
    "22": "1513",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "296125"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1281",
    "8": "1451",
    "9": "2285",
    "10": "2013",
    "11": "2917",
    "12": "2965",
    "13": "6437",
    "14": "9538",
    "15": "4269",
    "16": "3579",
    "17": "6257",
    "18": "7031",
    "19": "5187",
    "20": "2667",
    "21": "460",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "58337"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1514",
    "8": "577",
    "9": "3150",
    "10": "3106",
    "11": "2758",
    "12": "2891",
    "13": "5344",
    "14": "6653",
    "15": "3921",
    "16": "5171",
    "17": "5953",
    "18": "6143",
    "19": "5959",
    "20": "3255",
    "21": "150",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "56545"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "341",
    "7": "8838",
    "8": "12335",
    "9": "7872",
    "10": "4370",
    "11": "1829",
    "12": "3348",
    "13": "3502",
    "14": "5581",
    "15": "4231",
    "16": "2524",
    "17": "2236",
    "18": "2008",
    "19": "1796",
    "20": "4870",
    "21": "289",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "KOLAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "65970"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "644",
    "7": "6580",
    "8": "11336",
    "9": "4937",
    "10": "2282",
    "11": "1007",
    "12": "2973",
    "13": "5598",
    "14": "8371",
    "15": "5986",
    "16": "3312",
    "17": "4590",
    "18": "4617",
    "19": "3946",
    "20": "2184",
    "21": "3850",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "72213"
  }
]

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first
    
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
               // are number
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
  col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
           
      tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
              tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
              
      }
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
   table.classList.add("table-striped");
   table.classList.add("table-bordered");
   
   
  }
addTable(tableValue)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="newTable"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

for clarification refer the image
[image: reffer the image]

and i want all the numbers which are amount to be in a comma separator like 123456 should be 1,23,456

please help me in alingment guys i am stuck here not able to find any solution please

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition for your class adding.

```
//some code ...

for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++)
{
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++)
    {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (j > 1)  // <---------------------------- This one
            tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

    }
//the remain of your code
}
```

```js
tableValue=[
  {
    "5": "4341",
    "6": "12235",
    "7": "37135",
    "8": "53522",
    "9": "43688",
    "10": "39965",
    "11": "32024",
    "12": "49631",
    "13": "84770",
    "14": "107020",
    "15": "60046",
    "16": "50656",
    "17": "63183",
    "18": "63381",
    "19": "59317",
    "20": "49595",
    "21": "28752",
    "22": "1518",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "TOTAL 1",
    "TOTAL": "840779"
  },
  {
    "5": "605",
    "6": "6073",
    "7": "8324",
    "8": "15596",
    "9": "13424",
    "10": "15865",
    "11": "12101",
    "12": "16792",
    "13": "31889",
    "14": "39439",
    "15": "19949",
    "16": "17571",
    "17": "21105",
    "18": "20803",
    "19": "22551",
    "20": "19865",
    "21": "9632",
    "22": "5",
    "OUTLET": "JAYANAGAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "291589"
  },
  {
    "5": "3736",
    "6": "5177",
    "7": "10598",
    "8": "12227",
    "9": "12020",
    "10": "12329",
    "11": "11412",
    "12": "20662",
    "13": "32000",
    "14": "37438",
    "15": "21690",
    "16": "18499",
    "17": "23042",
    "18": "22779",
    "19": "19878",
    "20": "16754",
    "21": "14371",
    "22": "1513",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "296125"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1281",
    "8": "1451",
    "9": "2285",
    "10": "2013",
    "11": "2917",
    "12": "2965",
    "13": "6437",
    "14": "9538",
    "15": "4269",
    "16": "3579",
    "17": "6257",
    "18": "7031",
    "19": "5187",
    "20": "2667",
    "21": "460",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "58337"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1514",
    "8": "577",
    "9": "3150",
    "10": "3106",
    "11": "2758",
    "12": "2891",
    "13": "5344",
    "14": "6653",
    "15": "3921",
    "16": "5171",
    "17": "5953",
    "18": "6143",
    "19": "5959",
    "20": "3255",
    "21": "150",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "56545"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "341",
    "7": "8838",
    "8": "12335",
    "9": "7872",
    "10": "4370",
    "11": "1829",
    "12": "3348",
    "13": "3502",
    "14": "5581",
    "15": "4231",
    "16": "2524",
    "17": "2236",
    "18": "2008",
    "19": "1796",
    "20": "4870",
    "21": "289",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "KOLAR",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-01",
    "TOTAL": "65970"
  },
  {
    "5": "0",
    "6": "644",
    "7": "6580",
    "8": "11336",
    "9": "4937",
    "10": "2282",
    "11": "1007",
    "12": "2973",
    "13": "5598",
    "14": "8371",
    "15": "5986",
    "16": "3312",
    "17": "4590",
    "18": "4617",
    "19": "3946",
    "20": "2184",
    "21": "3850",
    "22": "0",
    "OUTLET": "",
    "BILL___DATE": "2018-08-02",
    "TOTAL": "72213"
  }
]

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first
    
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
               // are number
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
  col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
           
      tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
                if (j > 1) // <----------------------------There
                    tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
   table.classList.add("table-striped");
   table.classList.add("table-bordered");
   
   
  }
addTable(tableValue)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="newTable"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx it worked :).. can you please help me out to formatting the numbers with comma separator into Indian currency like 123456 =1,23,456..please

Comment: What about giving google a try for 30 seconds and find `MyNumberVariable.toLocaleString("en-IN");` ?

Comment: yup i knew this one but problem is what should i put in place of MyNumberVariable  because that are in json how can i use them

Comment: a small advice would be very helpful please what should i use in place of MyNumberVariable